# Exception throw behavior

Tags: c#, exception

So I have this exception I want to throw if something goes wrong. But it acts strange.

```
public Calendar LoadCalendar(){
    ...

    if (cal == null)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    _lastPollTime = DateTime.Now;
   ...
}
```

I expect this exception to be thrown to wherever LoadCalendar was called. Instead, the program stops at DateTime.Now; because of "NotImplementedException()".

What am I doing wrong? How could I throw it to the end of the method instead?

Comment: You could always just move _lastPollTime = DateTime.Now; above the exception if you want that to execute regardless of the Exception or not?

Comment: Recompile and run in `debug` mode.

Comment: Did you compile in release mode? With optimization debugger don't always "hit" right line number...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a "catch" clause somewhere up the call stack which receives the thrown exception and deals with it somehow.

You could try this in your programs Main function:

```
static void Main()
{
    try
    {
        // put existing code here
    }
    catch( Exception e )
    {
    }
}
```

Without a catch, the exception has no place to go to and so instead it causes your program to terminate.

These guidlines for working with exceptions might be useful to you: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET

Comment: The problem is that I want to throw an exception if cal == null to whomever called LoadCalendar(). But I guess I'll just have to do it differently.

Comment: @Ozitiho I'm interested... what would you like the whomever function that called LoadCalendar() to do in response to receiving an exception?

Comment: It's a HTTP server, I'll probably change it to a TimeoutException, make it catch that and respond with a 500 error.

Answer (score 0):

Just subscribe [DispatcherUnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.dispatcherunhandledexception(v=vs.110).aspx) event in `App.xaml.cs Class Constructor` and you can handle any application exception in this event.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        this.DispatcherUnhandledException += App_DispatcherUnhandledException;
    }

    void App_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        ////Handle your application exception's here by e.Exception.
    }
}
```